# Select Dropdown event return 'key:value' as target value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Wanted event to return e.target.value='NEW' instead of '1: NEW'

App.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="label">Status</label>
   <select (change)="changeStatus($event)" class="select-control form-control" 
    formControlName="status">
    <option *ngFor="let item of statusOptions" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

App.component.ts

```
statusOptions = ['NEW','PENDING','DENIED','APPROVED', 'ACTIVE', 'DEACTIVED'];
  
changeStatus(e) {
    this.clientRegForm.get('status').setValue(e.target.value, {
      onlySelf: true
    })
    this.val = this.clientRegForm.get('status').value;
 
    // getting val ='1:NEW' but want to get val='NEW'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do a workaround:

```
//Object.values() creates an array of all of the key values of the object
this.val = Object.values(this.clientRegForm.get('status').value)[0];
```

Im sure there is a better way to do this, but if you are really stuck and just want to move on ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't need to set value to the control in component.ts. It is set in the HTML page itself when we select options.

```
changeStatus(e) {
    //below statement is not required
    this.clientRegForm.get('status').setValue(e.target.value, {
      onlySelf: true
    })
    this.val = this.clientRegForm.get('status').value;
 
    // getting val ='1:NEW' but want to get val='NEW'
  }
```